# Is chai HTTP considered unit testing or integration testing?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, chai-http

The project I am working on has Cloud Functions written in `user-controller.ts`, and I am writing tests for these cloud functions using chai HTTP functions. Here's a sample of a test I am writing

```
it('should success and get all users', (done) => {
        chai.request(myFunctions.qa)
                .get('/getAllUsers')
                .set('x-api-key', API_KEY)
                .set('user-token', AdminToken)
                .set('content-type', 'application/json')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.be.a('object').with.property('status', true);
                    res.body.should.have.a.property('data');
                    const data = res.body.data;
                    expect(data).to.be.an('object');
                    if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
                        Object.values(data).map((user: any) => {
                            expect(user).to.have.property('firstName');
                            expect(user).to.have.property('lastName');
                        });
                    }
                    done();
                });
          });
```

I would like to know if this test is considered a unit test or integration test? If it's considered an integration test, how am I supposed to change it into a unit test?

Comment: Why do you think you need tests at a different level to the ones you have?

Comment: The diference between "unit" and "integration" test is more academical than practical. It doesn't really matters as long as you can run it as often as you need it, ideally with your entire test suite at every commit at least.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't actually, it's doing good job for me, my question is out of curiosity

Comment: @Alejandro thanks for the comment! I agree with you. But do you consider this type of testing unit test or integration ones?

Comment: @AliOz I don't even care about such formalization :). All I worry about is that I must click a single button and it must run as fast as possible. Another click and all tests must run and report a result.